# How to set up an alert system for Graphite+Grafana server

Tags: dashboard, graphite, grafana

I have a server *stats.hostname* with graphite + grafana. This is receiving some stats about geolocation from several clients. I want to know if there is some plugin/extension/external tool for alert (email) when this stats overpass some threshold.

I tried with worldPing, but I think the tool is only for checking is a site is reachable or not.

Can you suggest some solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alerting is probably one of the most requested features of Grafana. The team at Raintank are building an alerting system on top of Grafana. You can follow the progress and the discussion here - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2209

Currently though, you can use Bosun for your alerting needs. - https://bosun.org/quickstart#graphite

It does have Graphite querying capabilities, and there's a Bosun Datasource for Grafana as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alerting in grafana is available since release 4.0 from dec 2016 
http://grafana.org/blog/2016/12/12/grafana-4.0-stable-release/

Currently v. 4.0.2 is available http://grafana.org/download/ for donwload.